# Using OAuth with Facebook as provider with an IBM Cloud Functions managed API

Tags: facebook, oauth, vue.js, openwhisk

I am playing around with IBM Cloud Functions (OpenWhisk) and trying to setup authentication through OAuth with Facebook as the provider. I have setup an app with Facebook, I am able to successfully connect with this and fetch my token and I am able to verify this by fetching basic profile information (name and userID).

My problems starts when I enable OAuth in the IBM Cloud Functions API. I get a HTTP code 500 back from the call with very little information about what actually went wrong.

```
{"code":500, "message":"Oops. Something went wrong. Check your URI and try again."}
```

The only thing that is stated in the dashboard is:

> You can control access to your API through the OAuth 2.0 standard. First require an end user to log in via IBM Cloud App ID, Facebook, GitHub, or Google. Then include the corresponding OAuth token in the Authorization header of each API request. The authenticity of the token will be validated with the specified token provider. If the token is invalid, the request will be rejected and response code 401 will be returned.

With this information I got that I need pass the token with the Authorization header. My best guess is that the call fails somewhere when the token is being validated.

I am using Vue and Vue-axios to perform the API call. My current call looks like this:

```
  this.$http.get(API_URL+"?user_id="+localStorage.user_id,{headers :{'authorization':localStorage.token}}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

I have tried adding bearer/Bearer or token/Token in front of the token (some posts I read indicated that you should do this), but this had no impact on the response.

If I disable the OAuth authentication from the Cloud Functions side, the code above works and correctly retrieves the data (with or without the header option).

From the Chrome Dev tools it looks to me like the token is added correctly to the request, since the request headers have the Authorization header with the token.

I am not that familiar with OAuth or IBM Cloud Functions, so the problem might have a very easy fix. However, I am unable to find documentation which clearly shows me how I am supposed set this up. I am also unable to find any logs or more information about what actually fails here. Am I missing something obvious here?

Kjetil